# How does the adjust method work in Pandas ewm() function?

Tags: python, pandas

When calculating a exponentially weighted average in Pandas the parameter adjust is set to a default value of True.

I know what the adjust parameter does (but not how it does it which is what I want to know).

When adjust = True the ewa is calculated for every point in the sample but when adjust=False, then for a window of size n, you must wait for n observations to calculate the first ewa value.

I looked at the pandas documentation but it only proves that the adjust = True is equivalent to adjust = False for later values. It doesn't say how the earlier values are adjusted in the adjust=True case.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/computation.html#exponentially-weighted-windows

I even looked at the pandas code on github:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/window/ewm.py

see L99 onwards: but it just seems to be using the regular ewm formula for the earlier points?

This blog post demonstrates the difference between the two version of ewm based on the following data points:
https://towardsdatascience.com/trading-toolbox-02-wma-ema-62c22205e2a9

I tried to replicate the results in the blog post, for the earlier data points, using the formula in L99 above.

Where every time I calculate the mean I am using the current and all preceding ewm values.
Is this what pandas ewm function also use all previous values when calculating the mean?

```
i   Price    alpha^i       ewm                                                                   ewm.mean 
0               1
1    22.273     0.181818   =22.273*1/1 =22.273                                                    22.273
2    22.194     0.03306    =(22.194*1+22.273*0.03306)/(1+0.03306)=22.20615                        22.23958
3    22.085     0.00601    =(22.085*1+22.194*0.181818+22.273*0.03306)/(1+0.181818+0.3306)=22.10643 22.19519
```

The results are different to those shown in the blog post but if the method was correct they should be exactly the same.

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?